# path resolution in jinja2 templates

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm using cherrypy with jinja2 templates from a 'views' directory like this:

```
env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader('views'))
```

When I render the index page:

```
index = env.get_template('index.html')
```

it shows up fine, but referenced css, javascripts and images (inside the index.html) are not resolved:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/web.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
```

the file system is organized like: views/css , views/js , views/img

What is a robust way to obtain working file resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Static paths in Jinja's templates have nothing to do with Jinja. It's all about the configuration of the web server. If you're using flask, use `SharedDataMiddleware` dispatcher for static files, i.e.

```
from werkzeug import SharedDataMiddleware
app.wsgi_app = SharedDataMiddleware(app.wsgi_app,
                                    { '/static': '/path/to/static/files' } )
```

The structure of the static directory:

```
.../static/
           img/
           css/
           js/
           etc/
```

Don't forget to add slash at the beginning of the paths:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/img/favicon.png">
```

It is strongly discouraged to use `SharedDataMiddleware` on production servers. Nginx is the right thing.

Comment: I'm on a bit of a different setup, but the help carried through: I didn't have the slash at the beginning of my static paths. Now it all works, +1!